# Azure DevOps resource variables case-sensitive or not?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables, resource pipeline variable names are camel-case:

```
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID
```

I have a pipeline template that follows this, for example:

```
stages:
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), in(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/main'))
      stageName: Development
      ...
```

But that template (as can be seen above) invokes another one, which has

```
            steps:
              - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
                displayName: 'Download artifacts from build'
                inputs:
                  buildType: 'specific'
                  project: '17be1886-bedf-4a25-b77b-3a427a7ca351'
                  pipeline: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
                  specificBuildWithTriggering: true
                  buildVersionToDownload: specific
                  buildId: '$(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId)'
                  downloadType: 'specific'
                  itemPattern: 'drop/**'
                  downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

I, apparently, used Pascal-casing for "RunId" in the `buildId` parameter. Now, I've been having trouble in some cases getting the correct final result from this pipeline setup--but usually it's turning out correctly. However, I don't understand why it works at all. Since `buildType` is "specific" and `buildVersionToDownload` is "specific, `buildId` is required. Either this template should be rejected altogether because there's no such thing as `resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId`, or else it should fail at this step because that variable is null or empty or undefined or whatever, where it needs to be set to the ID of a real, existing build.

Is RunId being treated case-insensitively, as though I'd coded it as "runId", or is something else going on here?

Comment: It should no matter with case-sensitive, I think the issue comes from other places, see my answer, I also write a demo. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is RunId being treated case-insensitively, as though I'd coded it as
> "runId", or is something else going on here?

Yes, it should don't matter about the case-sensitive. I think the issue comes from other places.

> Now, I've been having trouble in some cases getting the correct final result from this pipeline setup

Could you please explain about this, how is the 'performances/behaves' of the pipeline on your side?

Do you mean the task wasn't be processed, or do you mean the artifacted downloaded was not expected?

Any way, the information you provided is not enough

---

## #--------------------------------------------------------------

I think I need to point out some issues based on the information you provided (if I understand your description correctly.):

```
stages:
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), in(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/main'))
      stageName: Development
      ...
```

**1, I notice the 'canRun' is defined by runtime expressions, this should not been used in parameters of template, parameters of template are compile time. You should use hardcode value or ${{parameters.somekey}} (parameter somekey is define in current YAML.).**

```
  steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        displayName: 'Download artifacts from build'
        inputs:
          buildType: 'specific'
          project: '17be1886-bedf-4a25-b77b-3a427a7ca351'
          pipeline: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
          specificBuildWithTriggering: true
          buildVersionToDownload: specific
          buildId: '$(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId)'
          downloadType: 'specific'
          itemPattern: 'drop/**'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

**2, The usage of $(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId) in this place needs you really defined resources in the YAML, otherwise the value will be NaN.**

**3, I notice you are using:**

```
buildId: '$(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId)'
downloadType: 'specific'
```

**I think it can transfer to:**

```
buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
```

## #--------------------------------------------------------------

A demo on my side that always works:

**pipeline for trigger purpose**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

**the pipeline be triggered by resources:**

```
trigger:
- none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SmartHotel
    project: BowmanCP
    source: Multiple_Repo_Trigger
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - '*'
pool:
  # vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), in(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/main'))
      stageName: Development
      buildPipelineId: Multiple_Repo_Trigger
```

**deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml**

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job_1
    steps:
    - script: echo $(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.RunId)
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      displayName: 'Download artifacts from build'
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: 'BowmanCP'
        pipeline: '${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}'
        specificBuildWithTriggering: true
        buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
        downloadType: 'specific'
        itemPattern: 'drop/**'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
y)'
```

Works fine on my side:

[image]

Comment: Re your response to my question, "es, it should don't matter about the case-sensitive. I think the issue comes from other places.", I'm sorry but I can't tell whether you're saying "Yes, these variables names are case-sensitive" or "No, these variable names are not case-sensitive."

Comment: A couple of responses to the rest of your commentary:

In most cases `canRun` as written _is_ correctly distinguishing those stages that are intended to run from those stages that are intended to be skipped. Also, you used the same expression in your example that you said always works as I used in mine where you said it was wrong.

I can't use 'latest' because if deployment to a given environment is suspended pending approval (which is a setting configured in the environment), once it's approved we still need to deploy the build whose deployment was suspended, not the latest one.